# How to avoid "Data Lake" menu item appearing in menu bar of Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-data-lake

When I start *Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 2* and open my [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) project, `Data Lake` item is not present in the main menu bar. But it appears later on, during development work. I did not notice so far on which particular action it appears. **Did you already notice which action makes `Data Lake` permanently visible?**

I would like to keep it hidden, because it causes keyboard shortcut conflict: its <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is already well-established way to open `Debug` menu (on the same menu bar).

Comment: i get it when I press ctrl+, (navigate to)
it is highly furstrating as it takes away focus from the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Data Lake menu item will show up when you use any of the Data Lake functionality.  For instance, if you open a Data Lake project or Navigate to a Data Lake Analytics Account in Server Explorer.  If you don't use Data Lake, you can uninstall "Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio" from the Control Panel->Programs.  If you use Data Lake, we'll look into fixing this shortcut conflict in future versions of the product.

Comment: Good, thank you. Besides the keyboard shortcut conflict, main source of trouble seems to be that even in *non-data-lake project*, `Data Lake` menu item appears on `Ctrl`+`,`. If the menu item was not automatically added when *Navigate to* (...to some ordinary item in non-data-lake project) is invoked, it would be a great relief.

Comment: The conflict with ctrl+, was causing the Navigate To menu to close after a few characters.